# What are the hours of the passport application counter at Lisbon airport

Tags: passports, eu-citizens, portugal, lisbon, lis

Lisbon airport has a one-stop dedicated counter (shop) for Portuguese citizens who want a passport. Is it open 24 hours?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Official website (in portuguese)](http://www.pep.pt/PagesPT/Passaportes/PEP/PEP1b.aspx) it is

- working days: 9 AM - 7 PM
- Saturdays: 9 AM - 2 PM
- Sundays: closed